# Android : why use a group notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I want my application to use Android notification, so I've been playong with it for a while to understand how they works.

After some try and reading the android documentation about it, I do not understand the need to use a group notification instead of a unique notification when I have sereral notification : if I detect beforehand how many notifications I need to display and push only one notification in case there is several, saying how many notif there should be, wouldn't it behave exactly like a standard group notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group, or stacked, notifications are there for Android Wear. Quoting myself, from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> If you are writing an email client, and you want to use a `Notification` to
>   let the user know about new email messages, you do *not* want to raise a
>   separate `Notification` for each email. Users will come to your home with
>   pitchforks and torches... and not to help you with farming.
>
> Instead, the vision is that you update an existing `Notification` with
>   new content. For example, you might start with a regular `Notification` for
>   the first received email. Then, when the second one comes in, you replace
>   that `Notification` with one that has a simple summary ("2 messages are in
>   your inbox!"), plus perhaps an `InboxStyle` "big" `Notification` variant
>   that could show the subject lines for both of those messages.
>
> Android Wear devices, however, add an interesting wrinkle: you want the
>   `Notification` to be informative about the event itself. You want the user
>   to be able to make an informed decision about whether they should pull out
>   their primary device to read the new messages, and that decision is only
>   partly based on how many messages there are. Users will want to know more
>   about the outstanding messages (sender and/or subject line) to help them
>   make that decision... at least to a point. If there are 57 unread messages,
>   users may get frustrated dealing with all of those as individual items
>   on the wearable itself.
>
> The pattern here, then, takes advantage of some "group" capabilities added
>   to `NotificationCompat`:
>
> - Raise one "summary" `Notification`, that will only be shown on the primary device,
>     with the same sort of "2 messages are in your inbox!" information that you
>     would have used without considering Wear
> - Raise individual notifications for individual messages that will appear
>     on the Wear device
> - Collect all of those in a "group", so the primary device shows only the
>     summary and the Wear device shows only the individual ones

Comment: I see. I didn't understood that from Android's doc. Thanks a lot.